# Why does a filter break the half-pixel trick for crisp 1px strokes?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm using the "offset everything by half a pixel" trick discussed in [the second answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589650/drawing-grid-with-jquery-svg-produces-2px-lines-instead-of-1px) to get a crisp 1px stroke on a shape.

(There are rounded edges involved, so the `shape-rendering: crispEdges` solution isn't viable here -- it makes the curved parts of strokes look terrible.)

How come adding a filter (I'm using a gaussian blur + offset filter to implement a drop shadow) breaks the half-pixel offset hack?

You can play with [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hVWAy/4/).

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="160%" height="160%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="10" dy="10" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="2" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(5.5,5.5)">
    <!-- This one has a blurry stroke -->
    <rect width="50" height="50" rx="5" ry="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="steelblue" filter="url(#f1)" />
    <!-- This one has a crisp stroke -->
    <rect x="150" width="50" height="50" rx="5" ry="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="steelblue" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Apparently I can't post inline images as a new user, but you can [this is an image of how the svg looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq00l.png).

Comment: I got it working (in Chrome at least) by setting `filterRes` sufficiently high (2 * the total height of the image + shadow). [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hVWAy/10/). I don't really understand why this is required, though.

Comment: You already figured this out, but the blur you were seeing is actually unrelated to the pixel snapping. When filters are applied browsers set a sensible filter resolutions as to conserve memory and speed, which in your case was too low. I extended your jsfiddle to illustrate the effects of filterRes http://jsfiddle.net/5ueck/

Comment: Also, the best practice when figuring out things on your own is to post your answer and then accept it (after two days, I'm afraid).

Comment: filterRes is now deprecated and has been removed from edge browsers

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the blurry edges, you can always experiment with adding an feComponentTransfer with feFuncA to manually manipulate the edge blur. Aka:

```
<filter id="fee" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="160%" height="160%">
    <feComponentTransfer>
          <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 1" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```